# How does one use Mono if you have to install an MSI file first?

Tags: mono

I have to set up a .NET program to access a power generator but the users are on OS X. I'm aware of Mono but the installer for the .NET program is an MSI file.

Do I need to install something like WINE first so I can run the installer? Seems rather pointless to use Mono if WINE is there as (I assume) the latter can run the .NET libraries directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the .NET program does run well under Mono then running it with Mono would be a better choice. You can extract the executables from the MSI using something like [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

It's like this:

Program -> Mono (Framework) -> System

Versus

Program -> .NET (Framework) -> WINE -> System

If the application has windows-based dependencies it's probably best to install it under Wine (since it likely won't run under Mono).

Comment: Interesting --- I had forgotten that one could get at executables in an MSI file (it's been years since I've bothered with Windows!). I'll try this. Thank you.

Comment: Let me know how it goes! The main pitfall would be those dependencies, like registry keys needed, running as a service, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The usual method is to quasi-port the Windows .NET program to Mono and OS X, i.e. create a Mac installer for it and/or use [macpack](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3aRunning_Mono_Applications) to create an APP bundle.

Comment: That's fine if it's your own program --- but I'm dealing with something from another vendor.

Comment: Copy the installation from a Windows machine?

Comment: Yeah, if one knew everything that the installer did, that would work. I know there are tools out there that can monitor an installation so worst case that will be something to try.

Comment: .NET apps are often very self-contained.

Comment: Which is why I'm hoping that the suggestion to extract the executable from the MSI will work.